# How to prevent the latest ImageMagick vulnerability?

Tags: linux, vulnerability, debian

According to the [CVE-2016–3714](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2016-3714) there are a some vulnerabilities in the ImageMagick program (4 packages) :

> Insufficient filtering for filename passed to delegate's command allows remote code execution during conversion of several file formats

There are others programs and command lines dependent on the `imagemagick` package, ( an example [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php)). By executing the ImageMagick program, an image file can receive malicious code.

What are the recommended steps to take in order to verify, secure and prevent the `ImageMagick` vulnerability until the patch will be available?

Comment: There seems to be a workaround there : https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1332492#c3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the page you linked, there's [a workaround](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=29588).

Add the following to your `policy.xml`:

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="EPHEMERAL" />
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="HTTPS" />
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="MVG" />
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="MSL" />
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="TEXT" />
```

This file can be found in `/etc/ImageMagick/`.

This prevents the ImageMagick coder modules from leveraging the access modules above, each of which are currently vulnerable to the command injection issue.

There are a number of documented PoCs for the bug over at [the oss-security thread](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2016/05/03/18), which can be used as a check to validate whether the bug is still present after applying the workaround.

Here are a couple examples:

**exploit.mvg**

```
push graphic-context
viewbox 0 0 640 480
fill 'url(https://example.com/image.jpg"|ls "-la)'
pop graphic-context
```

**exploit.svg**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="640px" height="480px" version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink=
"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<image xlink:href="https://example.com/image.jpg&quot;|ls &quot;-la"
x="0" y="0" height="640px" width="480px"/>
</svg>
```

Simply running `convert` against these will cause `ls -la` to be executed, the output of which will be displayed in your console if the vulnerability is present.

Comment: Thank you , the path to `policy.xml` on Debian is `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` .

Answer (score 3):

Here is a reference for you: https://imagetragick.com

According to that page, you should verify magic bytes for the file you are processing, and you should use a policy file to disable the vulnerable ImageMagick coders.

The site provides a sample global policy. However it is not one size fits all. You can use it as a starting point.

Comment: That website is awful vulnerability marketing with almost no technical information.